# GetterAndSetter returns empty ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-volley, getter-setter

I am adding String returned by Callback method from Volley's onRespond method.

I have already initialized GetterAndSetter Method inside OnCreate Method.

this is my code:

```
onRespond(){
       ...
       AddtoList(CreateURL, new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    getterAndSetter.addString(result);
                }
            });
       ....
}
```

My GetterAndSetter Class:

```
public class GetterAndSetter {
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addString(String string) {
        this.strings.add(string);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        return this.strings;
    }
}
```

I tries to get all the strings added inside of this getterandsetter's ArrayList via following code inside my another method :

```
void LoadImages(MainActivity mainActivity){
       ...
        List<String> details = getterAndSetter.getList();
        Log.d("gs", getterAndSetter.getList().toString());
       ...
}
```

As seen above, I tried to print log, but it print "[]"(Empty String). I have seen alot of Answers on Stackoverflow, but can't solve my problem.

Update : I am adding more code so that you guys can understand the problem.

My OnCreate Method :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getterAndSetter = new GetterAndSetter();
    LoadImages(this);
}
```

LoadImages :

```
private void LoadImages(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    mView.dismiss();

                    Log.d("Respone", "onResponse: " + response);

                    //  Used to Get List of Images URLs
                    getResponse = ParseJSON(response);

                    List<String> urlList = getResponse.get(0);
                    List<String> titles = getResponse.get(1);
                    List<String> details = getterAndSetter.getList();

                    Log.d("gs", getterAndSetter.getList().toString());

                    for (String urls : urlList) {
                        Log.d("urls", urls);
                    }

                    for (String title : titles) {
                        Log.d("tts", title);
                    }

                    for (String dt : details) {
                        Log.d("dts", dt);
                    }


                }
            }, error -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error Occured...");
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

ParseJSON method :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ParseJSON(String URL) {
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(URL);
            JSONObject photos = root.getJSONObject("photos");
            JSONArray photo = photos.getJSONArray("photo");

            ArrayList<String> listURLS = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> Titles = new ArrayList<>();

            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < photo.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject photosJSONObject = photo.getJSONObject(i);
                String FarmID = photosJSONObject.getString("farm");
                String ServerID = photosJSONObject.getString("server");
                String ID = photosJSONObject.getString("id");
                String SecretID = photosJSONObject.getString("secret");
                String ImageTitle = photosJSONObject.getString("title");

                listURLS.add(i, CreatePhotoURL(FarmID, ServerID, ID, SecretID));
                Titles.add(i, ImageTitle);

                String CreateURL = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=" + API_Key + "&photo_id=" + ID + "&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";

                AddtoList(CreateURL, new VolleyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        getterAndSetter.addString(result);
                    }
                });

                result.add(listURLS);
                result.add(Titles);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

AddtoList Method :

```
public void AddtoList(String CreateURL, VolleyCallback volleyCallback) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(CreateURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                JSONObject root;
                try {
                    root = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject photo = root.getJSONObject("photo");

                    String username = photo.getJSONObject("owner").getString("username");
                    String DateTaken = photo.getJSONObject("dates").getString("taken");
                    String Views = photo.getString("views");

                    String str = "Date Taken : " + DateTaken + "\n" + "Views : " + Views + "\n" + "User Name : " + username + "\n";

                    volleyCallback.onSuccess(str);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.toString());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

My CallBack

```
public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
    }
```

Comment: you don't add anything to the list, what else do you expect it to return?

Comment: Probably the list *is* empty...

Comment: Did you put a log in `onSuccess(String result)` method to get the value of result

Comment: I am adding values from onSuccess() method via callback

Comment: @AviPatel which is not called in the code you posted, so you are not actually adding values.

Comment: @yates, yes i have printed logs and getting strings which are not empty.

Comment: @AviPatel so, the `details` contains the strings, but the `Log.d` does not print anything, correct?

Comment: @Stultuske, I haven't added the code, but it's getting called via volleyCallback.onSuccess(str); method inside of my Volley's onRespond() method

Comment: Put some more code so that we could see what exactly is happening

Comment: You should iterate the list: `for (String str : details) Log.d("gs", str);` instead of calling `toString()' of the List-object -  independently from your problem.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti, No Actually I am Adding the string inside ArrayList, but while getting or adding I am doing some mistake by which i am getting empty list.

Comment: @ChristophS, I have tried it, but it didn't even print logs, because it's empty.

Comment: Shouldn't the parameter of `onSuccess` be of the type `JSONObject`? So calling the toString of this parameter may result in `null`, thus you are adding `null` to your list, so it's empty.

Comment: @AviPatel can you post some more code? How do you initialize `getterAndSetter`? The body of `AddtoList` method?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Wait I am currently Adding...

Comment: Where are you calling `foo()`? Be sure you don't call it before getting the response

Comment: @AlbertoMéndez, Foo() was my LoadImages Method, it was just to simplification. I have changed it.

Comment: And you don't use `onRespond()` callback as mentioned, you use `onSuccess()` ...

Comment: @ChristophS , Callback Added...

Comment: Place your logging inside `addString(String string){}` as last statement. Log `strings` list directly and see if it is growing on each event.

Comment: @ChristophS Yes it's growing... I have put Log.d("hi", this.strings.toString()); and it's giving me arraylist as String format and from that i got it. It's adding values 1 by 1 on every iteration..

Comment: @isnot2bad can you help me with this??

Comment: @cricket_007 Take a look

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to print the list BEFORE the callback is being invoked by Volley.

You parse a Json and for each element, you make a new request. After parsing the Json you print the list, it's empty because of the calls you make aren't ended at the moment you print the list.

You need to wait until all the request you start from inside the loop have ended.

Comment: I have a doubt. I am getting Strings via printing logs, inside my getter and setter. If your suggestion is valid then isn't logs inside getterAndSetter empty as well?

Comment: No, if you log the values inside the `addString` method, them shouldn't be empty

Comment: How can i access them, so that i dont get it Empty? I have also tried making arraylist of URLs and then pass it one by one, which is the same thing.